# JSP + ajx : updating div using innerhtml problem

Tags: ajax, jsp, innerhtml

In my main page I have a div:

```
<div id = "content"><%@include file ="loadData.jsp" %></div>
```

The loadData.jsp has a `<table> ... </table>` then  a div called `pager` to do the table paging:

```
<div id"pager"> ... </div>
```

So, when I click certain link on my main page the ajax will set request to load this loadData.jsp and I will do something like

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

to update the content of div content. My problem now is it work only on Chrome and Firefox, then when run in IE has this unknown runtime error. I had Google this problem mostly is because the innerhtml because my output has a div call pager. Any solutions? Thanks

```
var xmlhttp
function loadContent()
{
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
        return;
    }
    var url="loadData.jsp";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=getOutput;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
function getOutput()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return null;
}
```

so in my main file i have this link

```
 <a href="javascript:loadContent()>All</a>
```

then have a

```
<div id = "content"><%@include file ="loadData.jsp" %></div>
```

So, when i click the link this content will load new data, it works in firefox and chrome but not in IE, inside the loadData i have this

```
<table width="900" border="0" class="sortable" id="menuTable">
<thead>
  <tr align="left">
      <th width="60">ID</th>
       ...
      <th width="80">...</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

...
</table>
<div id="pager" class="pager">
               <form>
                  <select class="pagesize">
                      <option value="5">5 per page</option>
                      <option value="10" selected>10 per page</option>
                      <option value="15">15 per page</option>
                      <option value="20">20 per page</option>
                  </select>
              </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide more codes, it is not clear to identify the problem with only that. May I know how do you call the request and store it in your div. If its only working in Chrome or FF maybe your using only XMLHttpRequest() and not checking for ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

Comment: Do you have an option of using jQuery? If you do then using it would be worth your time as you would not have to worry about cross browser issues.

Comment: What exactly the error you've encountered? and is all the version of IE causing a problem. Seems your code fine, try also add this  ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") in your GetXmlHttpObject()

Comment: when i click the link, the table doesn't refresh and, the left hand bottom corner shown a warning icon and stated that unknown error

Answer (score 0):

I think your code fine, add some break point or alert messages to know where the problem lies. Then it's better you have a try catch in your code like this.

```
function GetXmlHttpObject() {
        var xmlHttp;
        try {
                // for firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
                // InternetExplorer
                try {
                        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                        try {
                                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e) {
                                alert("Browser does not support AJAX!");
                                return null;
                        }
                }
        }
        return xmlHttp;
}
```

Also in your `getOutput` check the xhr status `xmlhttp.status==200`. Put some alert message in this function so you will see if your code is passing here.